# Question concerning Qt, UWP, OpenGL (ES), and ANGLE

Tags: qt, opengl, uwp, angle

I have some questions concerning Qt, the Universal Windows Platform UWP, OpenGL (ES), and ANGLE:

How can 3d apps, such as the standard Qt cube example:

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtopengl-cube-example.html

be made compatible with the UWP, in general?

When just building (e.g. with QtCreator) and running the above mentioned Qt standard cube example, I get the following:

```
qt.winrtrunner.app: QEGLPlatformContext: Failed to create context: 3006
qt.winrtrunner.app: QOpenGLWidget: Failed to create context
qt.winrtrunner.app: QEGLPlatformContext: eglMakeCurrent failed: 3009
qt.winrtrunner.app: composeAndFlush: makeCurrent() failed
```

I use Qt 5.14.2 for UWP 64bit (MSVC 2017) and QtCreator 4.11.1 on Windows 10.

For comparison: On non UWP (e.g. profile Desktop Qt 5.14.2 MSVC2017 64bit in QtCreator), it works.

After some searching, I found out that by adding the lines:

```
QSurfaceFormat format;
format.setDepthBufferSize(24);
format.setSamples(4);
format.setStencilBufferSize(8);
format.setVersion(3, 0);
QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
```

before showing the MainWindow, the context creation error disappears.

But instead, a new error arises:

```
QOpenGLWidget: Failed to make context current
```

What actually does this error mean? And how is the linkage between the graphics rendering (which is translated from OpenGL ES to DirectX by "ANGLE") and the sandbox of the UWP?

Thanks and regards